# Table alias relabeling when performing subquery

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm trying to resolve an error that is generated when I perform a sql subquery when using the django extension djorm-ext-pgfulltext.

The error that is generated is

> invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks_bookmark"
>   LINE 1: ...ECT U0."id" FROM "bookmarks_bookmark" U0 WHERE (
>   ("bookmarks...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "u0".

The django queryset filter that generates the error is

```
shared_bookmarks = SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__in=Bookmark.objects.search(query))
```

The sql that is generated when query='html' is:

> SELECT "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."id", "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."created", "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."modified", "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."bookmark_id", "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."hot_score" FROM "bookmarks_sharedbookmark" WHERE "bookmarks_sharedbookmark"."bookmark_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM U0 WHERE ( (U0."search_index") @@ (plainto_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'html'))))

From what I have been able to research, the problem may be coming from the use of the extra() function in djorm-ext-pgfulltext, specifically the following line:

```
qs = qs.extra(select=select_dict, where=[where], order_by=order)
```

I have been able to resolve the problem by forcing the subquery to be evaluated using list.

```
SharedBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark__in=list(Bookmark.objects.search(query)))
```

but the memory overhead associated with loading each element is going to be prohibitive at some point.

I would like to resolve the error that will not require so much memory overhead. I have read the django documentation related to problems with using extra() and its recommendation to "look at the query produced and rewrite your where addition to use the alias given to your extra table" but I'm unsure where to find the correct alias and how to go about writing the proper sql that will generically (for any searched term) handle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### As to your error

There is no `SELECT U0."id" FROM "bookmarks_bookmark"` in your query.
There has to be some kind of misunderstanding.

#### As for the presented query

Another case for an [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join.

```
SELECT b.id, b.created, b.modified, b.bookmark_id, b.hot_score
FROM   bookmarks_sharedbookmark b
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   u0
    WHERE  u0.id = b.bookmark_id
    AND    u0.search_index @@ plainto_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'html')
   )
```

Should perform considerably faster if you have multiple matches in `u0` for a single row in `bookmarks_sharedbookmark`, because the `EXISTS` subquery can finish scanning as soon as the first match is found.